# DB2 Query error

Tags: javascript, node.js, db2

I am currently working on an application previously setup by some former devs for a small company. When checking the response object after making a PUT request to update the user's account info I receive this error:

**SQLSTATE=42601 SQLCODE=-104 Token , was not valid.**

I am assuming this means there is a "," somewhere that it doesn't belong, but I can't seem to find it.

**Here is the query:**

```
update
  @lib3.usermst
set
  usfirstn = upper('@firstnm'),
  usmidint = upper('@mi'),
  uslastn = upper('@lastnm'),
  usbusnam = upper('@busnm'),
  usaddr1 = upper('@addr1'),
  usaddr2 = upper('@addr2'),
  usaddr3 = upper('@addr3'),
  uscity = upper('@city'),
  usstate = upper('@state'),
  uszip = @zip,
  uszipext = @zipExt,
  usphone1 = @phone1,
  usphntyp1 = substr('@phoneType1', 1, 1),
  usphone2 = @phone2,
  usphntyp2 = substr('@phoneType2', 1, 1),
  usphone3 = @phone3,
  usphntyp3 = substr('@phoneType3', 1, 1),
  usemail = upper('@email'),
  usqrecid1 = @qrecid1,
  usanswer1 = upper('@ans1'),
  usqrecid2 = @qrecid2,
  usanswer2 = upper('@ans2'),
  usqrecid3 = @qrecid3,
  usanswer3 = upper('@ans3'),
  uschgdat = Current Date,
  uschgtim = Current Time,
  uschgusr = upper('@userId')
where
  usrecid = @clientId
```

Am I on the right track, or am I completely off?

**What it looks like in Node within an SQL object**

```
var SQL = {

  client_UpdateProfile: "update @lib3.usermst set usfirstn = upper('@firstnm'), " +
    "usmidint = upper('@mi'), uslastn = upper('@lastnm'), usbusnam = upper('@busnm'), " +
    "usaddr1 = upper('@addr1'), usaddr2 = upper('@addr2'), usaddr3 = upper('@addr3'), " +
    "uscity = upper('@city'), usstate = upper('@state'), uszip = @zip, uszipext = @zipExt, " +
    "usphone1 = @phone1, usphntyp1 = substr('@phoneType1', 1, 1), usphone2 = @phone2, usphntyp2 = substr('@phoneType2', 1, 1), " +
    "usphone3 = @phone3, usphntyp3 = substr('@phoneType3', 1, 1), usemail = upper('@email'), " +
    "usqrecid1 = @qrecid1, usanswer1 = upper('@ans1'), " +
    "usqrecid2 = @qrecid2, usanswer2 = upper('@ans2'), usqrecid3 = @qrecid3, " +
    "usanswer3 = upper('@ans3'), uschgdat = Current Date, uschgtim = Current Time, " +
    "uschgusr = upper('@userId') " +
    "where usrecid = @clientId",

... 
}
```

**Here is how the query is executed**

```
  module.exports.updateProfile = function (clientId, userId, req, callback) {
    var err = {};
    var data = {};
    var query = SQL.client_UpdateProfile;

    query = query.replace("@lib3", config.library3);
    query = query.replace("@clientId", clientId);
    query = query.replace("@firstnm", req.body.firstnm);
    query = query.replace("@mi", req.body.mi);
    query = query.replace("@lastnm", req.body.lastnm);
    query = query.replace("@busnm", req.body.busnm);
    query = query.replace("@addr1", req.body.addr1);
    query = query.replace("@addr2", req.body.addr2);
    query = query.replace("@addr3", req.body.addr3);
    query = query.replace("@city", req.body.city);
    query = query.replace("@state", req.body.state);
    query = query.replace("@zip", req.body.zip);
    query = query.replace("@zipExt", req.body.zipExt);
    query = query.replace("@phone1", req.body.phone1);
    query = query.replace("@phoneType1", req.body.phoneType1);
    query = query.replace("@phone2", req.body.phone2);
    query = query.replace("@phoneType2", req.body.phoneType2);
    query = query.replace("@phone3", req.body.phone3);
    query = query.replace("@phoneType3", req.body.phoneType3);
    query = query.replace("@email", req.body.email);
    query = query.replace("@qrecid1", req.body.qrecid1);
    query = query.replace("@qrecid2", req.body.qrecid2);
    query = query.replace("@qrecid3", req.body.qrecid3);
    query = query.replace("@ans1", req.body.ans1);
    query = query.replace("@ans2", req.body.ans2);
    query = query.replace("@ans3", req.body.ans3);
    query = query.replace("@userId", userId);

    DB.runQuery(query, function (err, data) {
      if (err) {
        err = ERROR.client_ProfileNotUpdated;
      } else {
        err = ERROR.client_ProfileUpdated;
      }
      callback(err, data);
    });
  };
```

Comment: Where is this Javascript or Node.js? What is the context?

Comment: Updated my question.

Comment: I see the same statement twice, but not any actual Node.js code. How do you execute that statement?

Comment: Updated again with where the query is executed.

Comment: Debug your code and dump the final SQL that gets submitted to Db2. Examine *that* string. You may find that the cause of the error is at least one un-escaped single-quote in one of the character strings.

Comment: Thank you, I will now. Are you saying you actually see that there is an un-escaped single quote or is that just a suggestion? @mao

Comment: I can't see your *actual* values (in those variables) which might have an unescaped quote, only you can do this by debugging. Hence the suggestion to sanity check the *actual final SQL* that goes to Db2 to find the issue.

Comment: Try `current_date` and `current_time` instead of `Current Date` and `Current Time` respectively.